# Plotting additonal data frame into existing figure blows up x_lim

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I try to put an additional plot into my existing axes the x_lim change. Any idea how to fix this?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Number':[1486092,1401266,905820,469867,70639]}, index =['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5'])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Total':[1886092,1701266,1205820,909867,90639]}, index =['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5'])
ax1 = df1.plot.bar(figsize=(19,9))
```

Gives me the first plot with the x_lim I want to keep. When I plot the second data frame:

```
df2.plot(ax=ax1,style='bx',marker='D',markersize=6)
```

the x_lim change.

[image: plot image]

Comment: when you say "proportion" do you mean the limit ? Around 1500000 in your case

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the plot. When I plot the second df, the bars are further apart and the first and last bar are only displayed half.

Comment: Yep, I write an answer, try it. But it may not answer your question as I do not get the same result as you when I plot your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `df.plot()` use lineplot by default, which changes the xlim. Onef of the solution is to fix the xlim in your case.

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Number':[1486092,1401266,905820,469867,70639]}, index =['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5'])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Total':[1886092,1701266,1205820,909867,90639]}, index =['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5'])

ax1 = df1.plot.bar(figsize=(9.5,4.5))
xlim = ax1.get_xlim() # records the x_lim

df2.plot(ax=ax1,style='bx',marker='D',markersize=6)
ax1.set_xlim(xlim) # set the x_lim with the recorded one
```